# StructTS (Kalman Filter) model in R is not fitting correctly

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, kalman-filter

I would like to use a Kalman Filter to forecast price levels in some financial time-series data. Some googling has lead me to a few functions in R namely StructTS and KalmanForecast. Currently I am using StructTS to fit a model to a subset of the data and then using the fitted model to forecast a few days into the future. The problem I am having is that the model does not seem to be fitting. Right now I'm not sure if I am training the model wrong? Or if the model is not converging using optim?

My code and an example output is shown below:

```
alsi <- read.csv("http://www.turingfinance.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/ALSI.csv")
alsi <- as.vector(t(alsi['ALSI']))

kDays <- length(alsi)
kDays.sample <- as.integer(kDays*0.9)

alsi.train <- alsi[1:kDays.sample]
alsi.test <- alsi[kDays.sample:kDays]

fitted.model <- StructTS(alsi.train, type = "level")

alsi.test.forecast <- KalmanForecast(n.ahead = length(alsi.test), mod = fitted.model$model)
plot.ts(alsi.test, col = 'blue')
lines(alsi.test.forecast$pred, col = 'red')

alsi.train.forecast <- KalmanForecast(n.ahead =  length(alsi.train), mod = fitted.model$model)
plot.ts(alsi.train, col = 'blue')
lines(alsi.train.forecast$pred, col = 'red')
```

[image]

As you can see, the model isn't really fitting. I have searched on Google quite a bit before posting this question, and I have read the docs in R for `?KalmanLike` and `?StructTS`. Please help. Thanks!

And just in case anybody else is working with Kalman Filters in R in the future, here is a link that I personally found quite helpful:

[Kalman Filtering in R (survey of packages)](http://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v039i02/v39i02.pdf)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics and not really a specific programming question. Perhaps it's better to ask this on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks for embedding the image, but this isn't about statistics at all. I'm not asking what Kalman Filters do / how they work, I am asking how StructTS works and whether I am using it correctly programatically speaking. Perhaps you can suggest a different title?